# Create live chat using node.js, websockets and socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I know how to connect from **client side** to **server side** using `websockets` by just writing this code :

`var connection = new WebSocket('ws://mywebsite-url.com');`

Now I want something like it in **socket.io** to create my live chat support system..

**Or**

I have to use websockets to pass values to node.js server and use socket.io to edit data and send it to the agent that will reply to the client?

Comment: [A tutorial of how to create a live chat system is actually featured on the homepage of socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), and doesn't explicitly use websockets. Is there something that you can't use from that tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your example in socket.io would be:

```
var io = require("socket.io")
```

on the server side and

```
var connection = io.connect()
```

on the client side, as well as linking the correct files in your html file:

```
<script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Also check out this helpful example: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: it got me this error on the client side :
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:///socket.io/1/?t=1466500351221. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: and when i checked it on host it get me this error :
`GET http://trafficpets.com/socket.io/1/?t=1466500656694 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614857/socket-io-cannot-load-xmlhttprequest-in-google-chrome

Comment: Essentially, you have to open your app as a client would.  This means typing into your browser: "localhost:*insert specified port number here*"